# How can i turn off data connection in android?

Tags: android, connection, broadcastreceiver, 3g, 3g-network

I've got a BroadcastReceiver that turns off the wifi..in the same i want turn off also the data connection..How can i do it? This is the code

```
public static class LowBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            wifi = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Turning off wifi..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".LowBatteryReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And your LowBatteryReceiver

```
/** FOR CLOSE WIFI **/

public static class LowBatteryReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if(intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW))
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Turning off wifi..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

/** FOR CLOSE MOBILE DATA **/

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if(intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW))
            try {
            ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
            Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
            iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
            Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
            Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
            Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: well, what i want is turn off also 3g data connection. Not only Wi-Fi..how can i do it?

Comment: Thank you!! Only two questions..is it possible insert the mobile data code inside the `onReceive` of the wifi connection? and it ask me to import `Field` but i don't know which one..

Comment: for import Filed : import java.lang.reflect.Field; and I don't understand your first question ?

Comment: sorry ok now it's ok..so, now on BATTERY_LOW the data connection would turn off right?

Comment: My phone battery isn't low right now, so I can't try this code but if battery is low, I think my first posts second part should work

Comment: ok, it goes :) i tried changing from BATTERY_LOW to BOOT_COMPLETED and it goes :) thank you!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />, <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />, 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> and perhaps necessary : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />